# TEMP_DATA value must be same but it is changing

Tags: angular, highcharts

In my application I have one function below filter `TEMP_DATA`(which has unfiltered list) than redraw chart with this filter.It work for first filter but for the second time it doesn't work because 
`el.TEMP_DATA` is also changing althought it must be same.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rw7owy)

```
perSelect(org){
    this.reports.filter(x=>x.TITLE==org).forEach(el=>{  
       el.chartOptions.series[0].data= el.c_personel.length!=0 ? el.TEMP_DATA.filter(y=>el.c_personel.map(x=>{return x.id}).join(",").includes(y.sicil)) : el.TEMP_DATA 
       el.updateFromInput = true;
   }) 
}
```

this is also my class

```
export class Oxy{
    public TITLE:string;
    public highcharts:typeof Highcharts=Highcharts;
    public chartOptions:Highcharts.Options; 
    public TEMP_DATA=[];
    public PERSONELLER=[];
    public c_personel=[];
}
```

`c_personel` fills with dropdown. `PERSONELLER` and `TEMP_DATA` fills when page is loaded. What can be caused to change `TEMP_DATA` ?

As I control problem occurs with `series: [{ data: datas, type: "scatter" }]`
this also updates `TEMP_DATA`

I want to update graph related to person filter. Graph shows selected personels' result . If not selected anything, show all data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: posted the solution below.

Comment: Could you provide a live demo that recreates the problem? You can use this demo as a starting point: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-bry7k
It utilizes official Highcharts wrapper for Angular: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rw7owy live demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your method to

```
perSelect(org){
    this.reports.filter(x=>x.TITLE==org).forEach(el=>{ 
      let that=this, datas=[], temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(el.TEMP_DATA));
      if(el.c_personel.length!=0){ var datas=temp.filter(y=>el.c_personel.map(x=>{return x.id}).join(",").includes(y.sicil)) }else{datas=temp;}  
      el.chartOptions = {
        chart: {  backgroundColor: "transparent" },
        title: { text: '' }, credits: { enabled: false }, legend: { enabled: false },
        yAxis: { max: 100, min:0, title: { text: 'Verimlilik - Performans - Kalite (PVK)'}},
        xAxis: { max: 100,  min:0,  title: {  text: 'Davranış'}},
        tooltip: { formatter: function () {return this.point.name+'<br/>' + 'Davranış: <b>'  + this.y + '</b>'+'<br/>'+  'PVK: <b>' + this.x +'</b> <br/>'+ 'Pozisyon: <b> '+this.point.position+'</b> <br/>'+'Departman:  <b> '+this.point.organization+'</b> <br/>' } },
        plotOptions: { series: {  cursor: 'pointer',   events: {  click: function (event) {  that.personelDetay( this.options.sicil)}}}},
        series: [{ data: datas, type: "scatter" }]
      }; 
    }) 
  }
```

Comment: Not working. wrote this `let temp=[...el.TEMP_DATA] ;
      if(el.c_personel.length!=0){ datas=temp.filter(y=>el.c_personel.map(x=>{return x.id}).join(",").includes(y.sicil)) }else { datas = [...temp] }`

Comment: try console logging temp?

Comment: I did first time full second time first filtered list

Comment: problem is  series: [{ data: datas, type: "scatter" }] here when I update data ,it changes temp_data also

Comment: try the method i changed above and please can you show the code of personelDetay method?

Comment: Not working personelDetay  is empty method for now. I will write it later.  I updated question with less code .Problem happends after I updated chart data.

Comment: try putting datas===TEMP_DATA as your last statement inside foreach?

Comment: and what is inside TEMP_DATA? objects?

Comment: array objects which cames with page load

Comment: ahh there the problem lies, even if you make copy of array, objects hold the same reference. need to deepcopy. wait

Comment: have changed my solution. copy paste it and try.

Comment: you copy pasted the whole thing? can you give a stackblitz?

Comment: what operation to perform and what is expected behavior?

Comment: when i filter users graph update for example when i choose one person in graph show that person data when chose two graph shows two when not selected anything it will show all

Comment: perSelect function get choosen  people from dropdown and filter it with whole data

Answer (score 2):

The issue arises because the default copy method is shallow. So apart from the primitive data types, changes to the the other types such as arrays, or JSON objects when shallow copied, will reflect on the original variable.

So, try deep copy methods such as `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));`
or `let var2 = [...var1];`

*Probably change the reference to the Chart Options.*